# Не получается перевести строку в число, что делать?

Tags: java

Не получается перевести строку в число, что делать?

```java
public void zadanie() {
    int num = 0;
    String s = "s: 1, 2, 3";
    String s1 = s.split(":")[1];
    String str = s1.split(",")[0];
    num_sch = Integer.parseInt(str);
}
```

Comment: Ну я думаю тут лучше всего было получить число регуляркой. Тогда у тебя не будет создаваться два промежуточных массива. Да и в ней можно будет избавится от лишнего пробела.

Answer (score 5):

В этом случае поможет это:

```java
str.trim()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло))

Answer (score 1):

Если задача извлечь из строки все цифры, то можно воспользоваться регулярным выражением:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "-jaskdh2367sd.27askjdfh23";
        int out = Integer.parseInt(text.replaceAll("[^0-9]", ""));
        System.out.println(out);
    }
}
//вывод: 23672723
```

Если Вам нужно оставить точки, то просто добавьте их в квадратные скобки регулярного выражения. Не забудьте в этом случае поменять int на double и изменить парсинг.

```
replaceAll("[^0-9.]", ""));
```